# How can I install the flash player for Chromium in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: flash, 16.04, chromium

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to install the adobe flashplayer for Chromium in Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash

Comment: @bodhi.zazen it doesnt work. I can enable the canonical partners but the adobe-flashplugin is still missing from the software center.

Comment: you need to tell us more then "it doesn't work" post the error message you are getting when installing.

Comment: @muru although I prefer peperflash and chromium, my understanding is pepperflash is now depreciated. See the wiki page I linked.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen hmm. Perhaps you can post an answer in the other post describing the change? Since no versions are mentioned, I'm guessing it's also applicable for other releases.

Comment: @muru - The op states it is not working, waiting on additional information.

Comment: I don't get it to install on 16.04 either: `E: Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate`. Again, this is on Xenial (16.04).

Comment: This question is not a duplicate!

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because the installation process of PPAPI Flash became much easier since Adobe started to release it for Linux and Canonical packaged it in `adobe-flashplayer`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Be sure to [enable the Canonical partners repository](/q/14629/175814) then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: There is no 'Canonical partners' repo on 16.04 (fresh install).

Comment: For now (October 2016, Ubuntu 16.04) I added canonical partner, installed adobe-flashplugin but I go in some pages who need flash, e.g. pond5.com (to edit a clip) and I see "Get the Flash Player to see this clip..." so it doesn't work I mean Chromium doesn't seem to have it, even if I just installed it. I restarted computer and browser, still same text telling to get flash player... any ideas?

Comment: @firepol: Works for me: https://i.imgur.com/RPjQsN4.png

Comment: Thanks so much, after a long journey I ended up here. Kubuntu had given me the flashplugin-installer instead, which does not work.

Comment: Additionally, I had to go to `chrome://plugins` and check `always allow execution` for the Adobe Flash Player plugin, otherwise some website would consider it is not installed.

Comment: chrome://plugins gives "This site can’t be reached" error.

Comment: i'm sorry , i know here is not the good place for asking this question , but what does the canonical partners repository's work ?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

works for chromium and firefox

Comment: Can you confirm that you're on 16.04?

Comment: It does in fact not work at the moment. 
Installing 3rd party applications in 16.04 is broken at the moment.
This is a bug that should be fixed in the coming days.
A bad alternative is to install chrome, it includes flash

Answer (score 0):

I stopped using Chromium, but I was using Pepper Flash for a while back then. It's deprecated now, adobe-flashplugin should be enough

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash

See also for detailled installation instructions: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Partner-Flash

Comment: just enabled the 3rd part canonical, but it is not there.